# Clear sheet including image without affecting named range definitions

Tags: excel, vba

This is a simple request. I am trying to clear the contents of a worksheet before copying over a range from another sheet. There are two things I want to make sure of:
1. The sheet I am copying into (Sheet1) has named ranges defined that make absolute references to cells in this sheet. I want to make sure that these definitions are not affected in any way. The contents will, of course, change when I clear the sheet and copy over data from the other sheet.
2. There are some pasted images in Sheet1. These also need to be cleared out.

I tried the following:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear
```

This seems to ensure point #1 above. Seriously, I don't think there is any danger of this being a problem, but just wanted to mention it. However, the images do not go away. Perhaps this is because I use .Cells.Clear? I can't delete the sheet. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Sub KleanUp()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes
        sh.Delete
    Next sh
End Sub
```